# How do I say this - Girl waving her hair sexily?

Tags: phrases

Look at this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GVNnkhGAiE
How do I put it into words?

For example : Girl waving her hair sexily?

Comment: I'd say _provocatively_ would be a good word as it expresses intent.

Comment: Actually, it's the camera and viewer who provide anything provocative. Not the girl.  A description is to shake out one's hair.

Comment: Agree with both you.

Comment: ... But they disagree.

Comment: @Lambie I wonder what you mean. Was the choice (shaking her hair) arbitrary on the producer's part -- he could equally have shown the woman carrying out a bag of garbage, because the camera and viewer could make anything provocative?

Comment: There are different sorts of hair flips...And a lot more comes down to body language and eye movement happening at the same time.. just as there are different ways a guy might preen his muscles or hold his posture.  Sometimes a muscular guy is "strutting" and sometimes they're merely walking...but most humans can tell the difference, especially within their own culture.

Comment: I'm reminded of the line by Julian Casablancas, "The room is on fire as she's fixing her hair."

Comment: @Chaim Girls (women too) shake out their hair all the time, even when they are alone or with other women. It is not necessarily provocative. If a woman looks straight at the man and does it, ok, it is conceivably provocative but the gesture in and of itself is really not. Also, this is not a "hair flip" regardless of Victoria's Secret marketing bumph. FLIP is not linguistically accurate. To flip something is a quick movement of a thing, like the page of a book.

Comment: @Lambie Black Dagger didn't say it's necessarily provocative. He asked for a word for those cases when it is sexy; I imagined that he in turn imagined it as flirtatious.

Comment: @Lambie But I realize too late: you were actually responding to Xanne's comment.

Comment: @Chaim No worries. It's a tricky business, women's hair. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is commonly known as a ***hair flip*** or ***flipping the/her hair***. For example:

> There is a very important, crucial-to-your-life topic I'd like to discuss today: **hair flips** and how to do them all sexy, Victoria's-Secret-style. ([Beth Shapouri, "Let Alessandra Ambrosio Show You How to Do a **Hair Flip** Like a Sexy, Sexy Boss", *Glamour*, October 29, 2014](http://www.glamour.com/story/let-alessandra-ambrosio-show-y))
>
> These photos of Amal Clooney demanded a new BK Thread dedicated to Champion **Hair Flipping**. Only the very few know how to employ **the hair flip** with such aplomb. (["Championship Hair Flipping/Flinging", Bitter Kittens blog, March 2015.](https://bitterkittens.com/discussion/398/championship-hair-flipping-flinging) Note that while the title includes "flinging", virtually all examples from the extensive entries in the thread use the verb *flip* exclusively. Check out the link for many, many images of hair flipping.)

The mainstream dictionaries haven't quite caught up to this usage, but Urban Dictionary has at least two relevant entries:

> [**hair flip**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hair%20flip)
>   what girls do 2 get attention from any cute guy looking at them, a form of flirting
>
> [**hair flipping**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hair%20flipping)
>   elaborate dark ritual used to attract male humans. Many techniques of hair flipping exist. consult a veteran hair flipper for advice.

Please note, however, that **a hair flip is not necessarily meant to be provocative or flirtatious**; it can also just be a way to get the hair out of the eyes, a nervous tic, etc. (When I do it, it's very often because I've got my hands full with a baby and a dirty diaper, and I'd like to keep both out of my hair—pretty much the antithesis of trying-to-be-sexy.)

As the second definition above suggests, there are a lot of variations on hair flipping; the one you linked to is a [*slow-mo(tion) hair flip*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow+motion+hair+flip%22&oq=%22slow+motion+hair+flip%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.3466j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22slow+motion+hair+flip%22&safe=active&tbm=vid) (see Google video results for many examples).

This style of letting-down-the-hair flip was used extensively in the original *Charlie's Angel's* television show, and the 21st century movie version capitalized on this with the slow-mo version, as in [Lucy Liu's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGnhhw_GrQg) of the iconic clip of [Jaclyn Smith removing a helmet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVtVru9KXao#t=00m48s) in the TV show's credits.

As I recall the cast talked about "hair flipping" in interviews at the time, and the phrase even made it into the script. From [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Charlie%27s_Angels_(film)#Dialogue):

> **(Natalie is flirting with Pete, the bartender. The Angels are communicating via Walkie Talkie)**
>   **Alex:** *(quietly)* Flip your hair.
>   **Natalie:** What?
>   **Alex:** *(quietly and impatiently)* Flip. Your. Goddamn. Hair.

(You can see a very [poor quality video of the scene here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHIeIcsfgiw) Probably NSFW.)

Comment: Mind blowing (as in what an excellently prepared answer)

Answer (score 0):

A "seductive," "flirtatious" or "sensuous" hair flip are alternate ways to describe a "sexy" hair flip, depending on the context.